# How to integrate winston logger into my php website?

Tags: php, node.js, winston

I created a winston logger using nodejs, and I have a system made in php, I want to integrate this winston logger into my php system. how can I do that?

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: why not just create your logging system in PHP? On the face of it, this request doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for the reply. Our lead developer required us to create a logger in nodejs, and itegrate it in php, because usng winston logger its easier to create a logger module. Thats why he wants us to use nodejs instead of php logger. My problem now is that php and nodejs integration, hehe

Comment: I'm a lead developer too, and from my point of view, I'm afraid that yours has got their priorities wrong. You should make a logging module which is directly compatible with every language you work in. Even if it means some duplication. A logging module really needs to be 100% reliable (otherwise what will log the fact that logging is failing? lol).

Comment: The problem you've got now that is whenever you want to log a message from PHP, you have to either a) make a HTTP request to an endpoint which nodeJS can respond to, or b) execute a node script from a command-line (via shell_exec() probably) and pass the message that way. There's plenty that could go wrong in either of those integrations - so you'll still need something on the PHP side anyway to alert you in case the integration is failing at any time!

Comment: There are some ready-made logging libraries for PHP anyway (e.g. monolog is a well-known one, but you can do a google search for more options) so it shouldn't be too much effort to just make a PHP-based logger which is then built directly into your application and will work reliably without needing to worry about HTTP connections or shell commands. That is by far the most sensible option. Use your nodeJS logger for nodeJS applications, and your PHP logger for PHP applications.

Comment: Is there a verbose thing in monolog? I'm trying monolog right now and its working, but monolog can't detect like error 404. it should log something like error 404 but it doesn't.

Comment: <code>public function monolog_logger() {
        global $CFG;

        // create a log channel
        $log = new Logger('name');

        $date = date("Ymd");

        $filename = $CFG->dirroot."/admin/tool/log/store/monolog/logs/".$date."-log.text";

        //$myfile = fopen($filename, "w");

        $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($filename, Logger::DEBUG));
        
        // add records to the log
        $log->error('error');
    }

Comment: I don't know specifically off the top of my head. You'd be better to ask a more detailed question about it, and tag it with relevant things (there is a [monolog tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monolog) for instance), then it will get in front of a bigger audience who may have more direct experience.

Comment: Im just new here in stackoverflow so i dont know how to paste codes here. any way thank you for ur response, you helped me a lot. Thank you. I think i just need further research about this monolog. ^_^ and Im still want to integrate winston to php. thanks.

Comment: Well you shouldn't paste code into comments anyway, it doesn't belong here. Like I said, ask a new question about the monolog topic, it's different than your question above. When you're creating a question, you can use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
 provided in the editor, to make the code appear nicely in the question text.

Comment: _"Im still want to integrate winston to php"_ ...and I still think it's a bad idea. But I gave you the earlier above of the possible ways you could do it.

Comment: Hello @ADyson, this is my new post for my question about monolog, please help me hehe. thank you,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64312227/how-to-record-logs-based-on-http-request-errors-using-monolog